# Editing genesis file in geth Clique

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, genesis, clique

I'm working on project using the geth clique.
I have 4 nodes running on the network.
I created the 5th node with:

> geth --datadir node5 account new

I have edited the `genesis.json` to add the account in the alloc.

Then I initialized the node with `geth init --datadir node5 genesis.json`.

When I tried to run the node using the command

> geth --datadir node5 --http --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner" --http.corsdomain "*" --ipcpath node5/geth.ipc --port 30311 --bootnodes enode://3c76b2ece2fdef0986d3b7df0a25b686ed565dce3c6ed8cd19408a8a920535a0e7599a938889f4c491e228717e437077b1fe85dae3b604fd6324e225bbd60190@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305  --networkid 12345 --unlock 0x75931B13Ede4dF63545F5dbf66fD9E449e43b3F9 --password node5/password.txt --authrpc.port 8558 --http.port 8549 --allow-insecure-unlock**

It doesn't sync with the 4 first nodes.
I think it's because editing the genesis file.

Comment: Anyone has the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

It is as you said. After modifying the genesis file the fifth node is in a separate blockchain because the genesis block is different from the others.

You could reset all the previous nodes and recreate them with the modified genesis file.

The alternative is to use the original genesis file to recreate the fifth node. The fifth node will be able to synchronise, but it won't be able to vote. You could add the node to the signers using clique [`clique.propose`](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-clique#clique-propose).